# Как получить инстанс FastAPI в работающем приложении не через роут(request)?

Tags: python, redis, fastapi

В состоянии инстанса FastAPI находится пул подключений redis который нужен мне не в запросе(роуте), а в бекграунд таске которая сама запускается раз в n минут.

Comment: Добавьте код, демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Comment: Коротко - можно синглтон какой-нибудь сделать или функцию с кэшированием, которая при первом вызове создает инстанс, при следующих - возвращает существующий. Но везде могут быть свои подводные камни, лучше видеть ваш код, чтобы понимать как лучше сделать.